# Transferring innodb table

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, percona, mysql-8.0

I have a 30GB innoDB-only database that keeps having `Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping`  when running `mysqldump -u root -p --compress --max_allowed-packet=1G  --net-buffer-length=32704  --single-transaction largedb> /home/backup/largedb.sql.gz` from the source server

I have net read and write timeouts set to `31536000` in `my.cnf`, and beyond this I cannot find any other information on why it would be losing connection.

So I decided that I'll just turn off mysql and rsync them. For tables under 1GB this worked out perfectly.
I first created the database and the table struct then ran `ALTER TABLE {table} DISCARD TABLESPACE` move the .frm and .ibd files into the database folder and then ran `ALTER TABLE {table} IMPORT TABLESPACE` which fixed all the tables except the main one.

The main table is 30GB  and when importing the tablespace it says `Error in query (1034): Incorrect key file for table 'main'; try to repair it` There is no additional information in `error.log`. I googled and it seems to suggest if you get this error but its an innoDB then you might be running out of diskspace in your tmpdir. My tmpdir is `/tmp` and I have 400GB free.

ANALYZE on table results in

```
InnoDB: Tablespace has been discarded for table 'main'
InnoDB: Trying to get the free space for table `db`.`main` but its tablespace has been discarded or the .ibd file is missing. Setting the free space to zero. (errno: 11 - Resource temporarily unavailable)
Trying to get the free space for table `db`.`main` but its tablespace has been discarded or the .ibd file is missing. Setting the free space to zero. (errno: 11 - Resource temporarily unavailable)
Operation failed
```

CHECK on table results in

```
db.main: InnoDB: Tablespace has been discarded for table 'main'
db.main: Tablespace has been discarded for table 'main'
db.main: Corrupt
```

Can anyone help me either get `mysqldump` to stop losing connection or how I can repair the innoDB table?
I am about to turn the table into MyISAM and rsync it

I am running Percona Mysql 8 (based off mysql 8).

Comment: why not setup replication and when the replica catches up - cut it off?

Comment: @akuzminsky I am a pretty new to the DBA world. Replication is my plan in the future but seemed like a lot of overhead to setup when I just needed to move servers for the time being. However, if you have a good tutorial for replication please link it

Comment: It might go faster if you write across the network instead of hitting the disk you are reading from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rsync a running database, but you know that since you said you stopped it.

I'd you rsync with the mysqld not running (or from a snapshot), you have to rsync the ib_logfile* and ibdata* files from the datadir. Then there is no need to `DISCARD/IMPORT TABLESPACE` either.

For a copy without shutting down the database, xtrabackup is probably the most efficient solution.

If you have existing databases on the target, you will need to `mysqldump --no-data dbname` and import on the target in order to re-create the table structure metadata, but you will have `FLUSH TABLE ... FOR EXPORT` in the source before copying across. Then they will be clean and can be imported with `ALTER TABLE ... IMPORT TABLESPACE`

Comment: wont rsync the ib_logfile* and ibdata* mess up the tablespace of my other innodb database and files?  The two servers have differing databases  but I only want to transfer over 1 common database

Comment: Ah, that changes things. I will update the answer.

Comment: I have little doubt your suggestion would of worked (so I will accept it) but I ended up just using xtrabackup (wanted to learn it anyways) which I was able to do a partial backup and restore to get just the table I needed.

Comment: for those who's reading and that might suggest using xtrabackup. there is an existing bug with partial backups at least for PS MySQL 8.0.x and PXB 8.0.x. (eg https://jira.percona.com/browse/PXB-2132). however partial backups in 5.7 and older versions still work.

Comment: To export a single _table_, see "transportable tablespaces"; make sure the page you find is up to version 8.0 (either Percona or not).